# Avalonedit nested code completion from xml file

Tags: avalonedit

I'm using Avalonedit in my wcf application. I have to implement code completion feature(intellisense).

---

**My Requirement**

I have an xml file with the following content.This xml data will be updated often.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeRegion>
   <Display_Window>
      <GreenButton>10,10,30,85</GreenButton>
   </Display_Window>
   <Insert_Window>
      <BlueButton>10,10,30,85</BlueButton>
      <YellowButton>10,10,30,85</YellowButton>
   </Insert_Window>
   <Search_Window>
      <RedButton>10,10,30,85</RedButton>
      <YellowButton>10,10,30,85</YellowButton>
   </Search_Window>
</RelativeRegion>
```

I want to insert intellisense for this data to my avalon editor like

```
RelativeRegion.Display_Window.GreenButton
```

- Is it possible to directly bind the xml data to avalonedit intellisense?
- Is there any way to implement this nested code completion?

---

**What I have done so far**

I googled a lot about avalonedit nested code completion and i didn't get anything about the nested thing. Finally I start with the available code from [AvalonEdit Code Completion Documentation](http://avalonedit.net/documentation/?topic=html/47c58b63-f30c-4290-a2f2-881d21227446.htm). But I think this will work only for single level and not suiting for my requirement. May be I am unaware of its the capabilities as a first time user of avalonedit.

Anyone tried the nested code completion. Is there any way to achieve this.
I can change the data format from xml to JSON or any other format if required.